# What is the relationship between normal vector and differential form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose that $M$ is a closed, orientable $n$-dimensional manifold. if $w$ is an $(n-1)$-form, then by generalized Stoke's theorem,

$$\int_M dw = \int_{\partial M} w.$$

For simplicity, let $n = 3$. I am currently looking at the divergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Differential_and_integral_forms_of_physical_laws), which states that:

$$\int_V \nabla \cdot F dV = \int_S F \cdot \hat n \; dS.$$

RHS of the equation, $dS$ is inherentaly a measure of 2-dimensional volume, so it must have something to do with 2-form. Note that:

$$\int_V \nabla \cdot F dV = \int_V \partial_x F_1 + \partial_y F_2 + \partial_z F_3\; dx\wedge dy \wedge dz,$$
and the only way to set up 2-form $w$ is $w = F_1 dy \wedge dz + F_2 dz\wedge dy + F_3 dx \wedge dy$ so that $dw = (\nabla \cdot F) \; dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$. My question is, what happens to $\hat n$ in the equation $\int_S F \cdot \hat n \; dS$? How does this equation relate to 2-form $w$? I thought about the duality between 2-form and 1-dimensional vector, but it did not give me a meaningful result.

Comment: If you search this site, you’ll find that this question has been answered before. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128164/relationship-between-n-1-forms-and-flux-of-a-vector-field-across-a-hypersu/3130472#3130472), for example.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534243/vector-field-and-2-form-correspondence-is-this-explanation-correct/3538169#3538169) for another.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! Your answers were insightful.